# How would Google respond to redirecting visitors clicking on SERP to another page, but not the Googlebot?

Tags: seo, redirects, pagerank, search-results

This page has a good PageRank on Google: `http://www.example.org/myrankedpage.php`

Many users search on Google and land on *myrankedpage.php* 
However, I would like for those users to be redirected to the homepage: `http://www.example.org/index.php`

Can I add a redirection to *index.php* (my homepage) without compromising the PageRank of *myrankedpage.php*?

The idea is to redirect only users coming from a Google search, and not to redirect Googlebot when crawling this page.

Comment: I think I understand your question. The problem is if you redirect one page to another, you lose all of the value of the page being redirected short of the value of links to that page. In other words, with the exception of links, the SEO value of the original page will no longer exist. The exact effect of the redirect all depends on the redirect, 301 or 302. Essentially, it does not matter, you will not get what you want. The one page being redirected to the other will lose its original value fairly quickly once the search engines discover the redirect. Cheers!!

Comment: The Googlebot might see this as [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking), which could result in a penalty for your site, so not a great idea. It prefers that you display the same content to it as you would to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic rule of Googlebot is that it is supposed to be treated like any other user. It is a scout that is sent ahead of the user and the user follows in its path. You don’t try to show Googlebot one thing and the user another.

Use the time you are spending on this to improve your content for your users. That is the best way to get better rankings in Google.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that, it is [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en), which is against Google Webmaster Guidelines.

**Better to link other internal sources from ranked webpages.**